# using celery to set crontabs from front end

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am discovering celery but have some problem doing what I really want.. following [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/#configuring-celery) to set up the celery instance is pretty straight forward. But following the [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) is not. I am using redis as my key-value DB. But my tasks does not seem to be scheduled properly.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_celery import make_celery
from celery.schedules import crontab


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['celery_broker_url'] = 'redis://localhost:6379'
app.config['celery_result_backend'] = 'redis://localhost:6379'

celery = make_celery(app)

@celery.task(name='flask_celery.test')
def test(arg):
    return(arg)

@celery.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')


celery.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'add-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'tasks.add',
        'schedule': 30.0,
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, using another simple example works fine:

```
@app.route('/<mystring>')
def process(mystring):

    mystring1.delay(mystring)

    return 'task sent'

@celery.task(name='flask_celery.mystring')
def mystring1(string):
    return string
```

So what is wrong with my crontab celery example? Eventually I am looking for a way to set tasks from front end, i.e schedule task to be processed sometime in the future.

Comment: Could you more explain about problem? Do you want to set task to queue? For example, user open some url. Will task should run after some seconds? Or task should run a few times(for example 3 times with specific interval)?

Comment: hmm, above crontab should be, according to the docs, running i) every 10 sec ii) every 30 secs, but non of them are working. However, in the end I want the crontabs to be scheduled from the front end, i.e user puts in when it should run "14 pm tomorrow" etc..

Comment: Did you research [periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.add_periodic_task)? Which version of celery are you using?